# RPM postinstall script missing?

Tags: rpm

I executed the following on xyz-3.0.rpm:
$ rpm -qi --scripts ~/xyz-3.0.rpm > list

Now here's what list showed:
$ cat list

```
postinstall scriptlet (/bin/sh): 
rm /opt/xyz/config/appkey.cfg
/opt/xyz/bin/setup
```

Now I see that the setup script was not added properly, and options are missing. It should have been called with a -i argument.

To fix this, my hunch was to go and search the .spec file which generates this rpm but within the spec file I did not see any setup script being called.

I believe I am looking into the right spec file but I don't see the setup script being called.

Is there a way I can extract the spec file from xyz-3.0.rpm? Or maybe modify the specfile to have setup run with -i argument?

Comment: Is there an error that you're seeing?  How do you know the postinstall script is missing?

Answer (score 1):

The command you ran to list the scripts within the xyz RPM was missing the -p or --package option that is needed to query an uninstalled package. The command should have been

`rpm -qp --scripts ~/xyz-3.0.rpm > list`

Answering your question, it would be possible to extract and modify the spec file from the xyz-3.0.rpm if and only if that rpm contains the spec file.